# ¿Como solucionar este error en Python flask? at-line or selector expected

Tags: python, flask

¿Cómo se puede solucionar este problema?

```
<style>
    body{
    background-image: url( {{ url_for('static', filename = 'bg.jpeg') }} )
    }
    </style>
```

Error -> ) expected
Error -> at-rule or selector expected

Esto sería algo de mi codigo, App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'flask_spets'
mysql = MySQL(app)
app.secret_key = 'mysecretkey'
@app.route('/')
def Index():
    #Hacemos la consulta para llenar la tabla y le pasamos los datos.
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts')
    data = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', contacts = data)
```

Luego tengo esto en 'layout.html':

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}">
```

Comment: Hice una prueba con la etiqueta style en un template de jinja (lo que usa detrás del telón flask para generar html) y no me da ese error. Para poder ayudarte más facilmente, de donde viene ese fragmento de código? Está en la carpeta statics? Es parte de un template?

Comment: Hola!
Tengo la carpeta templates y static, ambas están separadas. Ahora agrego el codigo así me entiendes mejor jaja

Comment: ¿Tenés la certeza de que no es necesario un `;` al final del valor de _background-image_?

Comment: Esta vez volví a probar pero con flask. Pero no logro reproducir el error. Cuales son los pasos que haces para obtener dicho error?

Comment: Video del mini proyecto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgCfZkR8wME&t=37s
Video del background image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioXPQn8IwWI&t=350s
. La verdad supongo que debe ser un error de mi netbook o la verdad no sé. Toca pasarse a otro framework jaja.

Comment: Probaste agregando el css dentro de la plantilla html usando la etiqueta style? Es lo que hacen en uno de los videos.